# Give a score to range queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to give a specific score to documents which match specific conditions.

If the price of the document > 500 000, the document win 1 point.
If the price of the document < 1 000 000, the document win another 1 point.

So a document with a price of 600 000 will have 2 points, and a document with a price of 3 000 000 will only have one point.

These conditions don't exclude documents, they only add a constant score to the document score.

How can I achieve that ? I tried to use a bool query, but I don't know how to specify the score I want :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "price": {
                            "gte": 500000
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "price": {
                            "lte": 1000000
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A should clause outside the filter context will by default have a score of 1. As long as you don't want to use other value, your query will work ( tested in ES7 ). But if you want to tweak the weight of each should clause, you will need to rely on the @Rob's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to handle such requriement.

My test data:

```
PUT so/doc/1
{
  "price": 100
}

PUT so/doc/2
{
  "price": 500
}
```

Query:

```
GET so/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "price": {
                "gte": 10
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "price": {
                "lte": 200
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

and the result is

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 2,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2, <-- got score from both functions
        "_source": {
          "price": 100
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1, <-- got score only from single function
        "_source": {
          "price": 500
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Tested with elasticsearch 5.1.1 so they may be some API changes with elasticsearch 7.x.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!